# PHP mysql insert not working without error check

Tags: php, mysql

My table has 2 fields a primary with auto increment and then entry_id

why does the below not insert in the table:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ecolog";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$entry_id = 5;

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (entry_id) VALUE ('$entry_id')";


$conn->close();
?>
```

but when adding a error check it does?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ecolog";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$entry_id = 5;

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (entry_id) VALUE ('$entry_id')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

cant get my head around why this would be happening.

Comment: Because in your error checking you do the query `$conn->query($sql)` your code without the error check does not have this

Comment: Well, in the first example you never actually execute the query.  In the second example you do.  Regardless of whether or not you check for errors (though you should), you still have to execute the query if you want to execute the query.